Splunk not showing my new index after I added it through the GUI
I'm in a Udemy class and I'm trying to work on the practice files. The new index I created isn't showing in my search. It is a csv file and I used an add on to help parse.

That's nowhere near enough information to work with.  How did you create the index and on which instance(s)? How are you searching for it?  Why did you mention a CSV file?Indexes are not CSV files.  Which add-on are you using and where is it installed?
